# How to tunnel mqtt sub data to pure data (pd) in bash

Tags: bash, sed, mqtt

```
mosquitto_sub -v -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1883 -t 'gyro' | sed 's/[^ ]* //' | pdsend 3000 localhost udp
```

this command doesn't output anything.
while it should output a value I receive over mqtt.

without `sed 's/[^ ]* //'` it would output: `gyro 23`

As output, I want to have a bare number (without gyro) :)

Comment: Not being familiar with the first and last command in the pipeline, you say that the `psend` would output the string `gyro 23`? In that case, why did you put the `sed` in the middle?

Comment: Because I just want the 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print only `23` from the output of `gyro 23`

**Option 1:** using sed to print only numeric.

```
mosquitto_sub -v -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1883 -t 'gyro' | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

**Option 2:** using awk to print the second field which is `23`

```
mosquitto_sub -v -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1883 -t 'gyro' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Second option doesn't give me an output :/

Comment: @J0r15 Try the updated first option again. and share the output of `mosquitto_sub -v -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1883 -t 'gyro'`

Comment: Your edit doesn't work either. Well, it works but the number that should appear in pure data is not there :(.

Comment: But it does appear in puredata without the ''sed" part. Which i find very weird.

Comment: Oh wait it works but it is super slow ??

Comment: I Fixed it! :D (in pure data).  I routed It so i could filter the gyro :D. I'm happy i was stuck on this for 2 days.. Thankyou for helping! @sivaprasath